# Spotify web-api, how to distinguish between album and single

Tags: spotify

When using the [Spotify web-api](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/) to get the albums from an artist, the list of albums is very large. The list contains both Albums as Singles. Is there a way to separate them?

For example:

http://ws.spotify.com/lookup/1/?uri=spotify:artist:6VSZeMeJlVPGoR2nfB6UxD&extras=album returns the following albums:

```
- Born In A Storm
- You Don't Have To Stay
- Blind Man’s Bluff
- Multicoloured Angels
- Multicoloured Angels
```

When you open the artist in the Spotify client via `spotify:artist:6VSZeMeJlVPGoR2nfB6UxD` you'll see that only the first result is an actual album and the rest are just singles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's currently no data exposed in the Web API which would solve your problem.